# I have a question about using Shared_Preferences in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, sharedpreferences

I have a question about using Shared_Preferences in Flutter.

My problem is that Shared_Preferences works fine in the Emulator,

but I don't even get a Shared_Preferences object when I actually connect my phone to the next line.

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    (() async {

      final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      bool res = prefs.getBool('autoLoginKey');
      String id = prefs.getString('autoLoginId');
      String pw = prefs.getString('autoLoginPw');

     
          Navigator.push(
              context, // 기본 파라미터, SecondRoute로 전달
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      MainPage()) // SecondRoute를 생성하여 적재
          );
        }
      }
      else {
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LoginMainScreen()
          )
          );
        });
      }
        })();

    super.initState();
  }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZZSC.png

Comment: are you sure you are calling await inside an asynchronous function? please post the full code

Comment: @Henok I editted my code Thanks.

Comment: @Henok If I debug the code,'final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();' Immediately afterwards, it goes to'super.initState();'.

Comment: try creating a separate function for it like `initiCode() async { //paste the code here}` and call this function inside initState.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping that async function in this

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  //Call your async function here
});
```